# Where can I find the complete properties / functions list of all internal object for Node.js?

Tags: date, random, node.js, internal

I read their API, however, there is nothing about Date object, or how to generate a simple random number (e.g. Math.random() ).  Those internal objects are different from the client side javascript ones.  so where can I find out ?  Thank.s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those internal objects are the same as the objects that run in google chrome.  They're provided by the v8 engine.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for the current release of NodeJS (v0.4.6) can be found here: http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.6/api/all.html

On the whole, many of the internal objects within NodeJS should be same as your expect to see on the client-side.

Loading up the REPL from my terminal, I see the following:

```
> Math.random
[Function: random]
> Math.random();
0.8805044267792255
> Math.random();
0.3855400965549052
> new Date();
Mon, 18 Apr 2011 21:58:19 GMT
> new Date();
Mon, 18 Apr 2011 21:58:20 GMT
```

Comment: they do have extend some functions.  e.g. for Date.  you can do Date.now(), which is not in client js.  let me loop up V8 API.